# Android MonkeyRunner exception

Tags: android, testing, jython, monkeyrunner

I'm trying to run MonkeyRunner Android test tool from Eclipse (4.2).
I installed Eclipse PyDev plugin, as well as Jython 2.5.1.
My PyDev interpreter is set to Jython / 2.5.

I created a Jython project in Eclipse with a simple jython file:

```
# Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
```

Now when I launch it from Eclipse (project > run as JythonProject), I'me getting the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\svnrepository\trunk\JythonProject\src\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
    at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(MonkeyRunner.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.NullPointerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a post of Diego Torres Milano how to configure PyDev to use it with monkeyrunner. I followed [his](http://dtmilano.blogspot.it/2011/03/using-android-monkeyrunner-from-eclipse.html) steps and in my case everything works fine.

In brief, at first you need to change your Android installation. You need to rename your monkeyrunner tool to something monkeyrunner-original. Then you need to write in the same folder shell script (name it monkeyrunner) that will invoke monkeyrunner-original in the specific manner.

Script for Linux:

```
# /bin/bash
if [ "$1" = '-u' ]
then
 shift
fi

exec /opt/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/monkeyrunner-original "$@"
```

Script for Windows:

```
REM
@echo off if("%1")==("-u") shift "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools"/monkeyrunner-original %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8
```

Then in Eclipse, you should define new Python interpreter (not Jython) and point it to the created script.